# Finding Column Names in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

How can I know the list of column names used in a particular SP? I dont need all the column names of tables used in it, but only Output Column names and Column names used in Join ?

Comment: What exactly do you have in Mind? Doing it programmaticaly rather than using Management Studio?

Comment: You could open the stored procedure and read it? If that's not sufficient, add more details as to why you want to do this and how complex the procedure is

Comment: @apomene Want to do it programmaticaly

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server 2012 and later, you can use `sp_describe_first_result_set` to get the column details of the first result set returned.  See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602(v=sql.120).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878602%28v=sql.120%29.aspx).

Example:

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set @tsql = N'EXEC sp_who;'
```

Note that this method will list only columns returned by the query, not those only used in join and where clauses.